# .net 4.0 Try/Catch not catching socket exception

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sockets

I have an C#/WPF multi-threaded application which makes 6 requests to a stock broker for options information.  Five of the six threads complete normally and produce the results expected; however, the last thread doesn't end normally.  If I let it continue I get a "Socket Exception occurred" and a message: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall in the dialog box. All of these requests use the same code and are duplicate requests except asking for information from different dates (different Uri in request).
Code is:

```
try
{
    dynamic v_WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create ( v_Uri ) as HttpWebRequest;
    v_WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create ( v_Uri );
    v_WebRequest.Method = p_Method;
    v_WebRequest.Headers.Add ( "Authorization", v_OAuthHeader.ToString () );

    if ( p_Postdata != null )
    {
        v_WebRequest.ContentLength = p_Postdata.Length;
        v_WebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        using ( Stream v_RequestStream = v_WebRequest.GetRequestStream () )
        {
            dynamic v_bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ( p_Postdata );
            v_RequestStream.Write ( v_bytes, 0, v_bytes.Length );
        }
    }

    dynamic v_Response = v_WebRequest.GetResponse ();
    string v_ResponseText = null;
    Stream v_Reader = v_Response.GetResponseStream ();
    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader ( v_Reader, Encoding.UTF8 );
    v_Reader = v_Response.GetResponseStream ();
    using ( v_Reader )
    {
        v_ResponseText = readStream.ReadToEnd ();
        v_Reader.Close ();
        v_Response.Close ();
    }

    return v_ResponseText;
}
catch ( IOException ex )
{
    Trace.WriteLine ( "TradeKingApi(Request): IOException: " + ex.InnerException.ToString () );
    return null;
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
    Trace.WriteLine  ( "TradeKingApi(Request): non-IOexception: " + ex.InnerException.ToString() );
    return null;
}
```

The "catch" blocks do not capture the exception.  When the exception occurs, the debugger is pointing to this line:

```
                dynamic v_Response = v_WebRequest.GetResponse ();
```

I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.  If I could capture the exception I could allow the program to continue by returning null to the caller and the request could be re-issued.

I do have a non-threaded version of this program that doesn't suffer from the same problem...each request returns the expected data.

Perhaps putting the try/catch around only the single "v_WebRequest.GetResponse();" statement would help?

I've tried cancelling the thread in the calling routine, but that doesn't cancel the hanging thread.
Any ideas on further debugging or an approach to allow continuation would be greatly appreciated.

Getting nothing from the community, this is what I did:
Well, I added a 4 sec. timeout to the HttpWebRequest so that the app wasn't tied up very long, on the Socket Exception I send a null back to the caller; I put the Task.WaitAny(taskArray) surrounded by a Try/Catch and catch the AggregateException and return from the original method in the MainViewModel.  Several things raise questions in my mind:
1.) why do I have to hit F5 to continue 5 times before it hits my "catch" block?
2.) why does the request timeout...1 out of 6 and a different one each time?
I did change the code to remove the "dynamic" types and don't know why the original author might have used dynamic in the first place.
I'm still soliciting any help in further diagnosing the timeout and why the one thread is hanging.
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic` for some of these variables?  `v_bytes` in particular just seems odd.

Comment: John, you are probably confusing the `var` and `dynamic` keywords here. The type of `var` is infered at compile time, while `dynamic` it is at runtime.

Comment: Well, I must admit that I picked up this sample code off the broker's website, so I don't know why the author used dynamic.  I've considered changing it to something else, but don't know what to use...

Comment: Just replace `dynamic` with `var`.  If you don't know what `dynamic` does, you shouldn't be using it.  It adds unnecessary overhead and eliminates some compile-time verification of your program.

Comment: It must be the runtime-variables(dynamics) getting undetectable In compiled blocks. The usage of dynamic Is mostly for boxing, It Is not suggested to use It for places where compiled code can do the stuffs for you.

Comment: When you say the catch blocks are not capturing the exception, have you set breakpoints in the catch blocks to verify this?  Or are you relying on the (lack of) console output?

Comment: Considering you say the debugger stops on that line when the exception happens, there is a good chance that you're setup to break when any exception is thrown, even caught ones. Go to the main menu (File, Edit, etc.) and choose `DEBUG -> Exceptions` and make sure `Thrown` checkboxes are unchecked. You could also just hit F5 to continue running your program when it breaks there.

Comment: No, haven't set breakpoints in "catch" blocks...will do that.  I see inside the response that _CoreResponse says the operation has timed out...but how do I capture that?

Comment: OK, set breakpoint and eventually if I keep hitting F5, it gets into the second "catch" block and back to my calling routine which ends up reporting an AggregateException.  If I run without debugging, the app just fails after the "socket timeout" occurs.

Comment: Well, you're "swallowing" the exception, so what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Yes, I'm "swallowing" it, then returning null to the caller.  The caller will check for null and move on...

Comment: Well, I added a 4 sec. timeout to the HttpWebRequest so that the app wasn't tied up very long, on the Socket Exception I send a null back to the caller; I put the Task.WaitAny(taskArray) surrounded by a Try/Catch and catch the AggregateException and return from the original method in the MainViewModel.  Several things raise questions in my mind:

Answer (score 0):

To finish this up and post my own answer, I offer the following:
1.) The original timeout and socket exception was fixed by setting the KeepAlive on the request to false (it's true by default).  This eliminated the original problem;
2.) The "catch" block was actually seeing the exception but I had to hit F5 in the debugger several times before it showed up.
3.) Changing from a dynamic type to var or HttpWebRequest had nothing to do with either issue.  Yes, I used something authored by someone else and didn't question every line of code, but I dare say, that are a lot more people out there that do this for the sake of getting a job done than not.
4.) I actually discovered the solution to the timeout by using a great web diagnostic program called "Fiddler" - check it out if you don't know of it already.